# Can I put AJAX calls in the presentational component, or should I extract a container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I spend a lot of time thinking about how to best structure things as cleanly as possible in React. Lately I've been getting hung up on whether React containers should do nothing but connect to Redux (or other data - a la Meteor) and render/return a single component, or if containers should also be in charge of event-handling as well. So for example, it's a toss-up between these two models:

## Model 1

```
// ThingContainer.js

import Thing from '../components/Thing';
export default someHigherOrderFunc(/* map state/data to props */)(Thing)

// Thing.js

export default class Thing extends Component {
  handleClick() { /* ... */ }
  handleMouseEnter() { /* ... */ }
  render() {
    // Other components rendered here, both container or presentational
  }
}
```

## Model 2

```
// ThingContainer.js

class ThingContainer extends Component {
  handleClick() { /* ... */ }
  handleMouseEnter() { /* ... */ }
  render() {
    // Now Thing can be stateless
    return <Thing 
      onClick={this.handleClick}
      onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
    />
  }
}

export default someHigherOrderFunc()(ThingContainer)
```

It almost feels like in model 1, `Thing` becomes its own container in a sense, which I'm not sure I like. Model 2 feels more natural, as `ThingContainer` is charged with not just dealing with data and Redux, but also handling events, firing off Ajax requests in `componentDidMount`, etc. With the first model, if I wanted an Ajax request to be invoked in `componentDidMount`, it would have to go in `Thing` which doesn't seem right.

I'm wondering if there are any particular advantages or pitfalls to either of these approaches, or if it just comes down to style/preference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with doing AJAX inside the “presentational-ish” `Thing` when it’s only a couple of methods, and this component is never used in different scenarios anyway. Don’t split behavior from presentation before you’re sure *how* the behavior changes  in different contexts.

That you have this dilemma means your component doesn’t need to be reused yet. In this case it doesn’t matter how you split it. Both ways work fine so I’d go for the simpler one (model 1).

Later you may realize that you want to reuse the same look-n-feel but trigger different AJAX calls, or compute the props differently. At this point you may want to remove the event handling from `Thing` and create several different `ThingContainer`s, each handling events and computing props a little bit differently. This is when separating presentation and behavior becomes useful.

Comment: It almost seems like you have some experience with React + Redux ;)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! And then if I want to have different containers that can all wrap `Thing`, then it just comes down to an issue of naming conventions (how to name several variations of `ThingContainer`).

Comment: Yeah. I don’t find naming to be a problem with real use cases. E.g. `List` vs `UserFollowerList`, `UserFollowingList`, `UserPostList`, etc.